# Could this strategy be updated to v4

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I have been trying to update this v2 strategy to v4 without any luck; I am wondering if this could be done without actually re-coding it from scratch.

I am still a beginner with pinescript, and I have tried everything for the last few hours without being able to get it to successfully load.

I would highly appreciate any help/input.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know certain changes when upgrading. Luckily, `pinescript` has a very good documentation. Pay close attention to some functions like `security` where the deafult value of a parameter has been changed.

Please read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_4.html) and try to upgrade to v3. After that, the auto converter should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, the link actually helped me out and I was able to successfully convert it to v4.